# jQuery smooth scroll to sections with current class

Tags: jquery

I am still learning basics of jQuery, I've got interesting code from one of user's answer from this site. But I need to add some functionality to it - I need to add current state to anchors when they reach corresponding sections. I need to set the class `.on-section`

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop':  $target.offset().top + 2
            }, 1000, function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
```

```css
.anchor-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 690;
    right: 5%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.anchor-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.anchor-menu ul li {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.anchor-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.anchor-menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffae2a;
}

.anchor-menu ul li a.on-section {
    background-color: #cb016f;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anchor-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#one"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#two"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#three"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#four"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<section id="one">
one
</section>
<section id="two">
two
</section>
<section id="three">
three
</section>
<section id="four">
text
</section>
```

Comment: You can use _addClass_ https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `addClass` functionality of jQuery.

To fix the scope issues create a variable called `self` with the value of `$(this)`.

Use `self.addClass('on-section')` to add the class to the anchor tag that has been clicked.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var self = $(this);

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop':  $target.offset().top + 2
            }, 1000, function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $('a[href^="#"]').removeClass('on-section');
                self.addClass('on-section');
            });
        });
```

```css
.anchor-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 690;
    right: 5%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.anchor-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.anchor-menu ul li {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.anchor-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.anchor-menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffae2a;
}

.anchor-menu ul li a.on-section {
    background-color: #cb016f;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anchor-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#one"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#two"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#three"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#four"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<section id="one">
one
</section>
<section id="two">
two
</section>
<section id="three">
three
</section>
<section id="four">
text
</section>
```

Comment: it doesn't seems to be working. When I modify the line to .$('.anchor-menu ul li a').addClass('on-section'); it works, but it adds this class to every anchors, not the clicked one.

Comment: Yes the `$('.anchor-menu ul li a')` selector will modify all anchors in the `.anchor-menu` container.  To add the class only to the anchor tag that has been clicked use `$(this)` as the selector.

Comment: but '$(this)' is not adding anything to the anchor... I run Your code, same effect

Comment: @Dawid there was a slight scope issue with your code.  Please see my updated answer and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: yeah it done it's job - thank You. One more thing though, my first section is already on top, so first anchor should be activated. How to do that? So I think it should check also the scrollbar position? I mean it should check all the time if the section is on viewport or not?

Comment: @Dawid you can just add the `.on-section` class to the html element so it will appear active when the page loads.

Comment: yes. but the problem with my code is that when user is not clicking the anchors instead he scrolls the page via scrollbars the script is not checking the sections and so it's not activating anchors. I guess it is impossible with my current code?

Comment: @Dawid you are correct, that would require extra functionality out of scope of this question.

Comment: thank You, I marked this question as solved and I am going to look forward extend it's functionality. Have a good day :)

Comment: @Dawid glad I could help!  Please also consider upvoting my answer if it helped you.  Thanks

Comment: I can't upvote yet, I have less than 14 points, after 15th it is available.